# Error 502 while loading javascript files

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, internal-server-error

We have a web application (C# mvc) which loads about 10 javascripts files. While using an internal network about half of these files will return error 500/502 in Fiddler and the IIS log. After hitting ctrl-f5 al javascripts are loaded correctly. But when a user navigates to another page the same thing happens. This only happens when a user is reaching the website from the internal network. When browsing from an eternal network the web app works without problem.

We think it might have something to do with a proxy server but are unsure where to start looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research it had to do with the network of our client.